# Greater time resolution using .NET Micro Framework on Netduino board (for dimming an LED)?

Tags: c#, .net-micro-framework, netduino

I'm programming a [Netduino](http://netduino.com/) board using the .NET Micro Framework 4.1 and want to get a higher time resolution than milliseconds. This is because I'm attempting to dim an LED by blinking it really fast.

The issue is that the sample code uses [Thread.Sleep(..)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) which takes a number of milliseconds.

Sample code from http://netduino.com/projects/ showing the issue in question:

```
OutputPort ledOnboard = new OutputPort(Pins.ONBOARD_LED, false);
while (true)
{
    ledOnboard.Write(true);
    Thread.Sleep(1); // << PROBLEM: Can only get as low as 1 millisecond
```

Even if there's another way to accomplish dimming by not using a greater time resolution, I'm game.

Comment: Personally I'd use hardware and talk to it via SPI or I2C eg http://www.ltech.cn/english/product/DMX-512-Driver.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question about getting a better time resolution, but it does solve your problem with changing the brightness on an [LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode). You should be using the [PWM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) module for the Netduino.

*[Netduino Basics: Using Pulse Width Modulation (PWM)](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/09/27/netduino-basics-using-pulse-width-modulation-pwm)* is a great article on how to use it.

Comment: I'll look into the pwm module likely during my next electronics class and then update this thread. Thanks.

Comment: Netduino 2 now lets you use a PWM channel with the on-board LED.

Answer (score 8):

I have had a similar problem in the past and used the following method to time in the microsecond range.  The first line determines how many ticks are in a millisecond (its been a while since I used this, but I think 1 tick was 10 microseconds).  The second line gets the amount of time the system has been on (in ticks).  I hope this helps.

```
public const Int64 ticks_per_millisecond = System.TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

public static long GetCurrentTimeInTicks()
{
    return Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware.Utility.GetMachineTime().Ticks;
}
```

Comment: NETMF doesn't seem to support the Timer constructor that accepts a TimeSpan object, which is what would allow John to set the period in ticks.

Comment: This works great, just wrote a quick Wait function.  

Dave, what are you smoking?  Not only does NETMF support a TimeSpan in the constructor of a Timer (look at the overloads, bro), but that's completely irrelevant to this solution.  Just sit in a busy loop and wait for the desired number of ticks to elapse.  See the function I added in the edit.

Comment: Handy to know but personally I'd still use PWM for the LED thing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a timer to raise an event instead of using sleep.

The Interval property on a timer is a double so you can have less than a millisecond on it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcs6ww8(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: I upvoted this before testing it... oops.  The interval is actually either an int or a TimeSpan, and looks like it has ms resolution as well.  Thus, I do not think this is a valid solution for John.

Comment: I take that back -- while I still need to test it, one of the other answers indicates that you can get the number of ticks per ms, and on my board I get back 10,000.  So 10 ticks per us isn't too shabby (if it actually works)  :)

Comment: This won't actually work.  While System.TimeSpan DOES have sub-millisecond resolution, it will NOT actually fire your event at the requested resolution.  Your best event is peeking at Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware.Utility.GetMachineTime().Ticks in a while loop.  As suggested below, TimeSpan has a static property which will tell you how many ticks are in a second, millisecond, minute, hour, etc...

Answer (score 0):

In his comment to [Seidleroni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4419805/575530) BrainSlugs83 suggests "sit in a busy loop and wait for the desired number of ticks to elapse. See the function I added in the edit". But I cannot see the function added to the edit. I assume it would be something like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware;

private static long _TicksPerMicroSecond = TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond/1000;

private void Wait(long microseconds)
{
    var then = Utility.GetMachineTime().Ticks;
    var ticksToWait = microseconds * _TicksPerNanoSecond;
    while (true)
    {
        var now = Utility.GetMachineTime().Ticks;
        if ((now - then) > ticksToWait) break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A point that you might not be thinking about is that your code is relying on the .NET System namespace, which is based on the real time clock in your PC. Notice that the answers rely on the timer in the device.

Moving forward, I would suggest that you take a moment to qualify the source of the information you are using in your code -- is it .NET proper (Which is fundamentally based on your PC), or the device the code is running on (Which will have a namespace other than System, for example)?

PWM is a good way to control DC current artificially (by varying the pulse width), but varying the PWM frequency will still be a function of time at the end of the day.

Rather than use delays....like Sleep....you might want to spawn a thread and have it manage the brightness. Using Sleep is still basically a straight line procedural method and your code will only be able to do this one thing if you use a single thread.